# Team Build can't access mapped network drive

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

In my solution, I have a reference to the assembly files which are placed in network place and mapped that network to a drive letter (P:). the project files are referencing the assemblies from that drive (like P:\Assembly.dll) also, I have the snk file to sign the assembly in the same network drive.
Now, I am trying to build the project using TFS 2010 Build. But, When I run the team build, it is throwing error saying

> CSC: Cryptographic failure while signing assembly -- 'Error reading
>   key file -- The system cannot find the path specified

Can anyone have idea about how to enable access to mapped network drive?

> Note: 
>   The build controller is running under a user who have mapped the
>   network drive and have permission to access the path.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

The build service runs under an identity that has no drives mapped. Instead of using the mapped drive, you can use the file share location (\myserver\myshare..\myfile)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Is there any way to map drives for that Identity?

Comment: Create a [pre-build script for the TFS build definition](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn376353.aspx) to run and [map the network drive](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10175893/cant-copy-files-to-unc-destinations-if-bat-file-is-called-via-scheduled-task) there. This works for me.