# how to capture output of script (using options) that is triggered by windows scheduler

Tags: ruby, sql-server, output, scheduler

I would like to capture the output of a script with options which is triggered by windows scheduler.
I found an stackoverflow post At:

[How do I capture the output of a script if it is being ran by the task scheduler?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8662024/how-do-i-capture-the-output-of-a-script-if-it-is-being-ran-by-the-task-scheduler)                                                                          the suggestion is to use the following.                                                            cmd /c yourscript.cmd > logall.txt

I am not sure how to use this as in scheduler I have the following set up:

```
Program/script:  C:\Ruby193\bin\ruby.exe
add argument:  .\download_xml.rb --instance=SERVER-SQL
Start in:  C:\Download_Reports\
```

Thanks

Comment: I would recommend that you modify your script to use [Logger](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.5/libdoc/logger/rdoc/Logger.html), if you can.

Comment: yes this works using logger thanks