# How to debug this scheduled .bat task in task scheduler using cmd and log file?

Tags: r, batch-file, cmd, copy, scheduled-tasks

I'm trying to basically run the following .bat file as a scheduled task, while also logging errors in a .txt file:

[image]

In the 'program/script' box, I just have cmd. Then in the add arguments box I have:

```
/k ""T:\Some_folder\mybatchfile.bat" >>"T:\somelog.txt" 2>&1"
```

This had been working just fine originally before I tried to add the log function  and calling cmd [explicitly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8662024/how-do-i-capture-the-output-of-a-script-if-it-is-being-ran-by-the-task-scheduler) as seen in several posts, but I'd really like to add this function. I'm using [/k](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/515309/what-does-cmd-c-mean) for now so that I can watch the cmd window as things happen, but plan to replace it with /c so it closes when its done.

I tried many permutations of where [my quotation marks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6376113/how-do-i-use-spaces-in-the-command-prompt?noredirect=1&lq=1) are but am not having a lot of luck. I'm also intentionally using >> vs > in order to [append the log](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8665989/3348414), not overwrite it.

The contents of the .bat file are basically:

```
"C:\RDirectory\R.exe" CMD BATCH          "T:\Some_folder1\Preworkforbatch.R"
copy T:\Some_folder2\some_data.csv       "C:\Users\ABC1\Another_folder"
copy T:\Some_folder3\some_more_data*.csv "C:\Users\ABC1\Another_folder"
```

I'm wondering if part of it is that T is a network folder that is mapped? Thanks for your help.

edit:

Here is more info on the task:

[image]

Comment: It may be possible that the user under whom the task is being run, does not have access to the network location. Whether that's because the network hasn't been established yet, or a permission issue, is unknown at this time, _(because you haven't provided all of the scheduled task information)_.

Comment: The user has access to the network location

Comment: ...and, what about the other information?

Comment: Have added an additional screenshot, let me know specifically if something else should be added

Comment: A cmd window will open and you will see no progress.  Open your logfile to see the progress.  Close and open the logfile to see more progress.

Comment: If I wanted to see the progress do I just add 'echo' after /c?

Comment: The log file is not updating unf

Comment: To notify a previous commenter mention their user name: `@som or @somebadhat` will both work.  See https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok this ended up working for me, by editing the batch file itself, and just running the batch file (not cmd explicitly) in the task scheduler:

**mybatchfile.bat:**

```
@echo on
"C:\RDirectory\R.exe" CMD BATCH          "T:\Some_folder1\Preworkforbatch.R" >> "C:\Users\ABC1\Logfolder\mylog.txt" 2>&1
copy T:\Some_folder2\some_data.csv       "C:\Users\ABC1\Another_folder" >> "C:\Users\ABC1\Logfolder\mylog.txt" 2>&1
copy T:\Some_folder3\some_more_data*.csv "C:\Users\ABC1\Another_folder" >> "C:\Users\ABC1\Logfolder\mylog.txt" 2>&1
```

Writing the log file to the network was causing errors. **Writing to the local computer** solved this issue. **Not using double quotes** also was key, instead just quotes around the file/path. This setup gives me an output for each line, so for every line 2>71 shows up, I get an output if there's an error or a completion message.

This is what the task scheduler looks like:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
"T:\Some_folder\mybatchfile.bat" >> "T:\somelog.txt" 2>&1
```

When redirecting the output of a batch file to a log file you will not see as much output in the cmd window.  You have to repeatedly open, close, open the log file to see your progress.  Use the title command in your batch to display progress info in the cmd window.

```
title This is %~F0.  The time is %time%.  The date is %date%.  SLEEP 3600 FOR :RECORDRADIO
```

[image: screenshot of task]

Comment: I cant see the full contents of add argument

Comment: 2>&1  no double quotes  are used.

Comment: When I try that the cmd window opens with just the cursor and nothing happens