# Process.start results in file not found even though the file exists

Tags: c#

I am using following code to open an arbitrary file with an arbitrary application that is installed on the system :

```
if (File.Exists(_document.DocumentFullPath))
{
    Process.Start(_document.DocumentFullPath);
}
else MessageBox.Show(string.Format("Document {0} does not exist!", _document.DocumentFullPath));
```

When I execute this code I see that the file.Exists returns true, so the file does exist. But then the corresponding application opens, for instance an image viewer or a pdf viewer depending on the file type (jpg or pdf) that I am trying to open, but it shows an error in that application that it cannot find the file. No exceptions are thrown.
This does not happen all the time but only for some files. 
If I try to open these files manually by copy pasting the content of DocumentFullPath in the explorer, then the file does open correctly in the applicable application.

Duh I don't understand what is wrong.
Example of a filename that don't work :

```
C:\Users\stuyckp\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\WPF\FrakoKlantOpvolgingWPF\FrakoKlantOpvolgingWPF\bin\Debug\ProjectDocumenten\11339_Wigbers\6197_koelkast \big-money.jpg
```

I am running on windows 10.

Comment: are you using absolute or relative paths?

Comment: Absolute paths, just like in the example.

Comment: Can you add the code that launches the process?

Comment: Apparently not for file.Exists.

Comment: @CodingGorilla, the code that launches the process is there. Or I don't understand your question.

Comment: Sorry... I failed at reading. :)

Comment: Your example of a filename that doesn't work has a space between "6197_koelkast" and the directory separator; I doubt your directory actually has a space at the end of its name.  Could it be something as simple as that?

Comment: If I change the path and remove that extra space, it works. So I guess I'll have to programmatically change the path. And avoid the user from ending with spaces to begin with. That is actually the root cause of this problem.

Comment: Seems to be an error with `File.Exists()`. It seems to trim trailing spaces from folder names.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you have spaces in the file path? File.Exists can handle spaces fine, presumably as can Windows Explorer, but it's possible that Process.Start cannot.

I think this is what you want bud. Use the process start using a ProcessStartInfo object with the file path with spaces passed as a string separately.

[Use Process.Start with parameters AND spaces in path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17321289/use-process-start-with-parameters-and-spaces-in-path)

Comment: This is a good point, should probably change the code to be: `Process.Start("\"" + _document.DocumentFullPath + "\"");`.

Comment: Process.Start can deal with it (works for me with for instance a text file) but maybe the viewer associated with the filetype can't.

Comment: Used that way as in the link. Path and filename seperately works fine.

Comment: Problem seems to be `File.Exists("c:\\folder       \\with spaces \\file.jpg")` returns `true` even if the "real" path is `c:\folder\with spaces\file.jpg`