# Run CMD command with file with spaces

Tags: android, windows, batch-file, cmd, adb

When I try to acess a file with spaces and then give them arguments, it doesn't recognize the path.
If I type following it works:

```
C:\Users\Valentino>cmd /C adb push "C:\Users\Valentino\Desktop\Test.dat" "/sdcard/"
```

[This works]

If I try following, doesn't:

```
C:\Users\Valentino>cmd /C "C:/Path With Spaces/adb" push "C:\Users\Valentino\Desktop\Test.dat" "/sdcard/"
```

[Here it says 'C:/Path' doesn't is a valid file]

Neither this:

```
C:\Users\Valentino>cmd /C "adb" push "C:\Users\Valentino\Desktop\Test.dat" "/sdcard/"
```

[Here it says that the syntax is incorrect]

How must the syntax be, in order to read that file with spaces and give them arguments?

EDIT: You can try this even if you haven't adb installed. You will se that it will always fail, even on a existing file

Comment: When dealing with paths in DOS, you need to use the back slash (\\), not the forward slash (/) - i.e., "C:\Path With Spaces\adb", **not** "C/Path With Spaces/adb".

Comment: @Tim It doesn't work. I just tried it. It says again 'C:/Path' is not a valid file'

Comment: "C:/Path" looks like you're still using a forward slash.  You need to use a back slash for DOS paths - C/Path....

Comment: @Tim I tried both... / and \

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spaces problem in CMD !](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6376113/spaces-problem-in-cmd)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For using `cmd` command you need to use `"Your File Name"` ..

Here is an example..

```
keytool -exportcert -alias "your name" -keystore C:\Users\Desktop\your.keystore | C:\openssl-0.9.8k_X64\bin\openssl sha1 -binary | C:\openssl-0.9.8k_X64\bin\openssl base64
```

**Edited :**
You can use below command for path in cmd :

```
cd "Path With Spaces"
```

For more detail, Refer this link and accepted answer..!!

[How to use spaces in CMD?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6376113/spaces-problem-in-cmd)

Hope It will help you.

Thanks..!!

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but its not in that where i'm stuck. I want to acess a file with paths and give them other arguments and files within paths

Comment: @  Fusseldieb : Welcome..!! :-p

Comment: Edit your post and put the solution here too, it will be easier to find later.

Answer (score 1):

As [explained here](http://ss64.com/nt/cmd.html) you can run `cmd` like one of this:

```
cmd /C ""C:/Path With Spaces/adb" push C:\Users\Valentino\Desktop\Test.da /sdcard/"
```

or

```
cmd /C ""C:/Path With Spaces/adb" "push" "C:\Users\Valentino\Desktop\Test.da" "/sdcard/""
```