# C# run process with multiple spaces in arguments

Tags: c#, windows, command-line, command, escaping

I'm trying to start a process which contains multiple spaces within the arguments. The arguments that are passed are dynamically built. For example:

```
// These three strings will be built dynamically
string consolePath = "C:\\My Path\\nunit3-console.exe"
string dll = "C:\\My Path\\My.Test.dll"
string where = "--where \"test == My.Test.Example \""

string cmdText = $" \"{consolePath }\" \"{dll}\" {where}";
//cmdText = "\"C:\\My Path\\nunit3-console.exe\" \"C:\\My Path\\My.Test.dll\" --where \"test == My.Test.Example \""

var processInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe", $"/c {cmdText}");
processInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
Process process = Process.Start(processInfo);
process.WaitForExit();
process.Close();
```

This does not work as any text beyond the first space will be ignored. I will get a message such as *'C:\My' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.*

I tried adding parentheses around the arguments, as noted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6376113/how-do-i-use-spaces-in-the-command-prompt), but it didn't work. What is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably have to add a further double-quote around anything that may include spaces within *one single* argument. Usually a space means the end of an argument. So to preserve this, you´d have to put the string into double-quotes.

So consolePath should actually be this:

```
var consolePath = "\"C:\\My Path....exe\"";
```

Comment: I changed it to `var processInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe", $"/c \"{cmdText}\"");` and it works perfectly. Thank you for clarifying.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to previous answer, `@` could be used to avoid `\\` like this:

```
@"""C:\My Path\nunit3-console.exe"""
```

or:

```
"\"" + @"C:\My Path\nunit3-console.exe" + "\""
```

More about `@` here:
[What's the @ in front of a string in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/556133/whats-the-in-front-of-a-string-in-c)

Comment: @HimBromBeere, should it be like this: `"\"" + @"C:\My Path\" + "\"";` ?

Comment: Either this or `@"""C:\My Path\nunit3-console.exe"""`.

Comment: Thanks, @HimBromBeere. Updated.

Answer (score 0):

After searching two days for working string I finally found it.

Just wrap string like this:

string Arguments = "/c **"**"path" --argument **"**";

```
string Arguments = "/c \""path" --argument \"";
```

Notice bold quotes from first string.