# not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file. gcloud invocation failed

Tags: r, windows-10, google-cloud-sdk

I just installed the google cloud package on R (cloudml). When I submit a job to the cloud I get this error message:

> Error: ERROR: gcloud invocation failed [exit status 1]
>
> [command]
>
> cmd /c C:\Users\vidar\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\bin\gsutil.cmd ls -p
>
> [output]
>
> [errmsg]
>   'C:\Users\vidar\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.

Installing the cloudml package in R took care of installing Google SDK and I didn't get any error message or anything during the installation process.

Any idea why I get this error message?

Answer (score 2):

You are getting an error in this command:

```
cmd /c C:\Users\vidar\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\bin\gsutil.cmd ls -p
```

because it includes a space in the path (in `Cloud SDK`). From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6378038/9251751) answer in an older question:

> You have to add quotation marks around each path and also enclose the
>   whole command in quotation marks

In your case:

```
cmd /c ""C:\Users\vidar\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\bin\gsutil.cmd" "ls -p""
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. My problem is that I'm working with the cloudml package in R and I don't know how much control I have. I.e. I'm just using a function and I don't know how I can add quotation marks around the path. Any idea?

Comment: Can you provide some more details on what you do? Do you follow the steps [here](https://tensorflow.rstudio.com/tools/cloudml/articles/getting_started.html)?

Comment: Yes I followed these steps. I tried this on my PC at work and my laptop at home and I get the same error on both of the computers. I'm using Windows 10.

Comment: @ViðarIngason did you manage to get a fix? I have the exact same issue

Comment: @Shinobi_Atobe no I didn't. I think I ended up using a macbook.

Comment: I solved it last night by re-running `cloudml::gcloud_init()`

Answer (score 0):

Please run following command to resolve the error

```
 gcloud_init()
```

refer to article for details

[rstudio with cloudml on GCP](https://tensorflow.rstudio.com/tools/cloudml/articles/getting_started.html)

Packages should be installed in following manner

```
install.packages("cloudml")
library(cloudml)
gcloud_install() # install the SDK using the 
gcloud_init() #  default account, project, or region you can use the gcloud_init() function
```