# Regarding spaces in directory address in cmd prompt

Tags: python, selenium, cmd, allure

Hello fellow engineers,

I am trying to run allure reports (to generate the html ones) with below command

```
allure generate C:\Users\Rahul Jain\PycharmProjects\Pytest_Selenium\JSON --clean
```

But getting below error:

```
C:\Users\Rahul does not exist
Jain\PycharmProjects\Pytest_Selenium\JSON does not exist
```

I think this is happening due to spaces between Rahul and Jain.
I did google and found few tricks to resolve it  but nothing is working for me-

Below are the commands I tried, but not working for me-

```
"allure generate C:\Users\Rahul Jain\PycharmProjects\Pytest_Selenium\JSON --clean"
"allure generate "C:\Users\Rahul Jain\PycharmProjects\Pytest_Selenium\JSON" --clean"
```

Would appreciate if you have any other resolution

Comment: Have you enclosed your command in quotation marks?  See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6376113/how-do-i-use-spaces-in-the-command-prompt#6378038)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I use spaces in the Command Prompt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6376113/how-do-i-use-spaces-in-the-command-prompt)

Comment: You're supposed to quote the path/filename, not the whole command: `allure generate "C:\Users\Rahul Jain\PycharmProjects\Pytest_Selenium\JSON" --clean`

Answer (score 2):

`allure generate "C:\Users\Rahul Jain\PycharmProjects\Pytest_Selenium\JSON" --clean`

The path needs to be in quotes (`" "`), not any parts of the command you are trying to run.

Comment: Sorry,,, its not working as well.Getting below error now 
'C:\Users\Rahul' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.