# Command Prompt Broken

Tags: command-prompt

My Command Prompt is Broken
When I start a file in **C:/users/Guo Xin** it will say `windows Cannot find C:/users/Guo` 
It can't read folder/file with **Space** in the pathname
**Please Help me fix this Broken Command Prompt**

[image: Example Photo]

**#Broken Command Prompt #Command Prompt Error**

Comment: You might want to look at other questions like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6376113/how-do-i-use-spaces-in-the-command-prompt

Answer (score 4):

Wrap your path with quotation marks:

```
"C:/users/My name"
```

Also, this is not "broken command prompt", that's how every terminal works.

Comment: [Watch This Video](https://files.fm/u/t62urp86w#/view/gar9u3pe8)

Comment: @ChanGuoXin Do not use the `start` command, as it creates a new command prompt (you don't need/want). Also, when the first argument of the `start` command is a string with quotes (`"`) it is used as the title for the new window, not for the program you want to executed.