# npm run dev when i run this command this type of error happend

Tags: reactjs, next.js, vite

My package.json the vite version is `"vite": "^5.0.10"`,
node version is `node 20.0.0` npm version `npm 9.6.4`

is there any way to solve this issue?

[image: this type of error happend here.]

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the space character in the path `C:\Users\Masudur Rahman\.vite-plugin-mkcert\mkcert.exe` as one can see in the error message.
There are several options to solve that, for example:

- Place the file `mkcert.exe` at a path that contains no spaces.
- Change the calling source code, so it can handle spaces in paths.
- Escape the space character in the path (if possible), so the call succeeds

Maybe [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6376113/how-do-i-use-spaces-in-the-command-prompt) is also helpful.

Answer (score 0):

i deleted node_modules forlder and package-lock.json file and re install the project.
I just genarate this 2 files and give the authorization for mkcert. and it works for me.
C:\Users\Masudur Rahman.vite-plugin-mkcert\dev.pem
C:\Users\Masudur Rahman.vite-plugin-mkcert\cert.pem

[image]